# Regex For Minimum Length Between Whitespace

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not great at regex but I can usually figure it out; here's my problem:

I want to check a string to see if it has at least 10 characters, but I want to ignore beginning and ending whitespace.  Here are some samples of what I'm trying to match:

`s = space`

`|...| = match`

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
----------------------------------------
|ABCDEFGHIJ|
sss|ABCDEFGHIJ|s
ssss|123s45s567|ssss
|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP|ssssss
```

The regex I'm trying to find should return true for the 4 examples above. The 3rd one is the one I'm having issues with.  I can't get it to ignore whitespace on the boundaries, while still counting it between.

I'm using C#4.0 if that matters.  I have to use regex, I can't do stuff like string.Trim() or anything operations like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^\s*[^\s].{8,}[^\s]\s*$` does what you're after.

Optional whitespace, followed by a non-whitepace character, followed by at least eight other characters, followed by non-whitespace, followed by optional whitespace.

The key is ensuring you have non-whitespace on either end of the internal 8+ characters (and of course, 8 + 1 + 1 = ...).

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I had to take out the second * but other than that perfect! `^\s*[^\s].{8,}[^\s]\s*$`

Comment: Second * taken out - my apologies!